# Some technical details about regular functions on quasiprojective varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have some confusion about some very basic notions in algebraic geometry.  I am using Shafarevich but I find the book to be pretty unclear at times.

First, given a quasi projective variety $X$ over an algebraically closed field $\mathbb{k}$ (meaning $X$ is an open subset of a closed subset of projective space) when defining what it means for a function $f:X\to \mathbb{k}$ to be regular on $X$ is it the same thing to say "there are homogeneous polynomials $p$ and $q$ in $n+1$ variables of the same degree such that at every $x\in X$ we have $f(x) = p(x)/(q(x)$" and "about each point $x\in X$ there is an open neighborhood of $x$ in $X$ such that $f$ is the quotient of two homogenous polynomials in $n+1$ variables of the same degree"?  In other words I am asking if, in the Zariski topology, a function locally looks like a quotient of two rational functions must it globally look like a quotient of two rational functions?  This is obviously not true in the usual topology on $\mathbb{C}$ for example but I am confused about the case of the Zariski topology.

Something else I am confused about is the following.  If we have a regular function $f$ on a quasiprojective variety $X$ then the set $X - Z(f)$ is an affine variety.  This I understand.  But it is stated in Shafarevich that that the ring of regular functions on $X-Z(F)$ is the ring of regular functions of $X$ adjoin $\frac{1}{f}$.  It is clear that this is contained in the ring of regular functions, but I don't understand how we know that this is the entire ring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question, if $X$ is affine, then $f$ can be seen globally as a polynomial. I believe Shafarevich proves this.

If $X$ is an irreducible quasiprojective in general, let $f=p/q$ locally at a point $x$, for $p$ and $q$ polynomials. If $y\in X$, let $f=r/s$ at $y$. Define
$$Y=\{z\in X:p(z)s(z)-q(z)r(z)=0\}.$$
This is a closed subset of $X$ (since the equation above is homogeneous and can be seen as defining a projective variety which we then intersect with $X$). Moreover, since $f=p/q$ (likewise with $f=r/s$) on an open (and therefore dense) subset of $X$, we see that this closed set contains a dense open set of $X$. Therefore $X=Y$.

**Conclusion:** You can define $f$ as $p/q$ wherever $q\neq0$. If $q(z)=0$ for some $z$, then you need another representation for $f$ at $z$.

**Example:** Take $X=\{x^2+y^2-1=0\}\subseteq\mathbb{A}^2$ and $f(x)=x^2/(y^2-1)$. $f$ could possibly have a pole at $y=\pm1$, but when we use the identity $y^2-1=-x^2$, we see that $f(x)$ is actually the constant function $-1$. This is a very boring example but it gets the point across.

For your second question, take a look at Lemma 2 in the section of Quasiprojective Varieties. First assume that $X$ is affine. The equations that Shafarevich finds for the affine variety $X-Z(f)$ are basically the equations for $X$, except that you can replace $T_{n+1}$ by $f$. Try to write the coordinate ring using this, and then see if you can generalize this to an arbitrary quasiprojective variety.

Comment: So basically in an irreducible variety if a function is locally rational it can be viewed as "globally rational" in the sense of being viewed as an element of the field of fractions of the ring of regular functions, but we might not necessarily find a representation which gives all function values?  What then in the case of a non irreducible variety?

Comment: Yes. If the variety is not irreducible, you have to look at each irreducible component.

Comment: So is there an actual example of a variety and a function which is locally rational but not globally rational?  Does this mean that regular functions do not form a sheaf structure on an arbitrary variety?  Or do we simply choose to define a regular function as one which is locally rational so that the gluing axiom is automatically satisfied?

Comment: The problem is that it is more complicated to talk about a rational function when your variety isn't irreducible, since the coordinate ring will no longer be a domain. Regular functions can be made into a sheaf by defining a regular function to be locally rational and defined at every point.